# What might cause "ng: not found" when running an Angular App in Azure AppService?

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops

I've created a new Azure AppService WebApp. The main settings were

- Publish: Code
- Runtime-stack: Node 10.14
- OS: Linux

My app runs ok locally. When I deploy to the Azure service from a Azure Devops Release Pipeline I get the following error.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

If I publish to an WebApp running with a Windows OS it works fine.

ERROR

> 2019-06-18T01:47:21.769001402Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
>   2019-06-18T01:47:21.769008803Z  2019-06-18T01:47:21.769016003Z
>   Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
>   2019-06-18T01:47:21.769023403Z NodeJS quickstart:
>   https://aka.ms/node-qs 2019-06-18T01:47:21.769030703Z NodeJS Version :
>   v10.14.1 2019-06-18T01:47:21.769038103Z 
>   2019-06-18T01:47:22.048648425Z Generating app startup command
>   2019-06-18T01:47:22.078479171Z Found scripts.start in
>   /home/site/wwwroot/package.json 2019-06-18T01:47:22.100794280Z Running
>   npm --prefix=/home/site/wwwroot start 2019-06-18T01:47:23.491524256Z 
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.491583557Z > portal@0.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.491595757Z > ng serve -o
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.491604458Z  2019-06-18T01:47:23.548311196Z sh: ng:
>   not found 2019-06-18T01:47:23.580009577Z npm ERR! file sh
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.590153263Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.590644872Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   2019-06-18T01:47:23.611089046Z npm ERR! syscall spawn

Comment: Will you share your `package.json` file, please?